# while for loop combination can't end up while loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, break, continue

I'm developing a script to check if a data frame's column's sum is over three with a certain interval.

```
loc_number = 10 # start loc image number with 10
k = 2
while k < 3: 
    for i in range(0, int(len(target_df.index)/loc_number), loc_number):
        print(range(0, int(len(target_df.index)/loc_number), loc_number))
        print(loc_number, i)
        loc_target_df = target_df.loc[i: i+loc_number].sum(skipna=True, axis=0)
        print(loc_target_df)
        if any(x < 3 for x in loc_target_df):
            loc_number += 1
            print('heloo')
            break
        else:
            print('here')
            pass
    print('probably')
    continue
```

It seems at the beginning, it goes to 'if' and print out 'heloo' for a while, which means the sum of the certain column's values isn't over three. Ok. it's what I wanted.

However, when it goes to else, which means the cloumn's sum is over three, it should go to next 'for loop' not 'while'. but it goes to while loop again and again, so print out like this:

```
here
probablay
range(0, 14, 322)
322 0
10.000000     272
26.400000     210
31.680000     106
38.016000     113
45.619200     215
54.743040     146
65.691648     224
78.829978     255
94.595973     321
113.515168    308
136.218201    356
163.461842    270
196.154210    190
235.385052     97
282.462062     47
338.954475     32
406.745370      6
488.094443      3
dtype: int64
here
probablay
range(0, 14, 322)
322 0
10.000000     272
26.400000     210
31.680000     106
38.016000     113
45.619200     215
54.743040     146
65.691648     224
78.829978     255
94.595973     321
113.515168    308
136.218201    356
163.461842    270
196.154210    190
235.385052     97
282.462062     47
338.954475     32
406.745370      6
488.094443      3
dtype: int64
here
probablay
range(0, 14, 322)
322 0
10.000000     272
26.400000     210
31.680000     106
38.016000     113
45.619200     215
54.743040     146
65.691648     224
78.829978     255
94.595973     321
113.515168    308
136.218201    356
163.461842    270
196.154210    190
235.385052     97
282.462062     47
338.954475     32
406.745370      6
488.094443      3
dtype: int64
here
probablay
range(0, 14, 322)
322 0
```

what's the problem of my while for loop ?? and how to make the for loop work?

Comment: You don't change `k` anywhere inside the while loop

Comment: What _do_ you want to happen?

Comment: @Jasmijn what I want to do is keep running 'for loop' under else condition.

Comment: That already happens. You don't even need the `pass` there, because it literally does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer to the first question, maybe you could provide a bit more detail on what it should do once it passes the `else` then. I have the feeling you want the code to do something completely different than what it does right now.

I hope it helps, although it is quite some text.

Let's look at the execution:

- you define your variables `loc_number = 10, k = 2`.
- the code checks, if `k < 3` which is true.
- you define a range from 0 to `int(len(target_df.index)/loc_number) = 450` in steps of `loc_number = 10`, which is an iterator which will set `i = 0` in the first iteration
- Now that `i = 0`, the code prints `10 0` and you calculate the sum of all elements of the dataframe from row `0` to row `i + loc_number = 0 + 10 = 10`. This returns a value for each column, which is again printed.
- Now, you check if any of those values is *smaller* than 3 (`x < 3`), and if so, you increase `loc_number` by `1` (`loc_number = 11)`, print `'heloo'` and break out of the `for` loop.
- The code prints `'probably'`
- As `k < 3 == True`, you initialize a new for loop with `range(0, 409, 11)` (ranging from `0` to `14` in steps of `11`), which will again set `i = 0` in the first iteration.
- Now that `i = 0`, the code prints `11 0` and you calculate the sum of all elements of the dataframe from row `0` to row `i + loc_number = 0 + 11 = 11`. This returns a value for each column, which is again checked if any of these is smaller than 3.
- As this is the case, `loc_number += 1 = 12`, it prints `'heloo'` and you break out of the for loop again. The code prints `'probably'`
- This is repeated until `loc_number = 322`. Now, the `range(0, 14, 322)` only returns `0`, so the `for` loop only sets `i = 0`, and you sum from row 0 to row 322, the code prints `322 0`
- Now, no value is smaller than 3, so the `any(x < 3)` evaluates to `False` and the `else` is invoced. There, `loc_number` stays the same and the code prints `'here'`.
- As the `for` loop does not find another element in the `range()` iterator, the `for` loop is ended and the code prints `'probably'`.
- You now initialize a `for` loop with unchanged `range(0, 14, 322)`, which executes the same as before, no value is smaller than 3.
- This circle never breaks, as the `while` statement is always true.

Perhaps one point of confusion is, that the `for` in python behaves like `foreach` in other languages.

Also, I'd suggest to run the following code snippet to better understand the `range(start, stop, step)` function, as I think this also behaves differently than you assumed:

```
for i in range(0, 5, 2):
    print(i)

for k in range(0, 5, 10):
    print(k)
```

Comment: Ahh yeah I realized there was a problem with range. I set the higher step value than the stop value. Thanka!!!